# Storing Outlook Messages and Contacts in one place

Tags: office365

I am using Office 365.

Is there a way of creating a project or task 'application'/'folder' that can store emails and contacts associated with that project or task? I want to be able to drag and drop each message or contact so I can look them up at a later date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately an Outlook folder can contain items of only a single type (although mail folders can contain Post items as well).